# Integrate Spring MVC with Wildfly Security Domainand Java Security

Tags: spring-mvc, security, jax-rs, wildfly

I have an application with Spring MVC 5 running on Wildfly 14.

Wildfly has a configured security domain and I'm trying to understand how to get relative informations using Spring MVC.

In older applications I can use the security domain informations with EJBs: for example, I can access caller information in a stateless EJB with the SecurityContext:

```
@Context
private SecurityContext sec;

@GET
@Path("test")
@PermitAll
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public MyResult test() {
    Principal principal = sec.getUserPrincipal();
    boolean isUser = sec.isUserInRole("USER");
    return new MyResult(isUser +" Hello, " + sec.getUserPrincipal() + "!");
}
```

To use SecurityContext and PermitAll annotation I've used Resteasy (provided by Wildfly) enabling it in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now I'm using Spring MVC and I don't find anything to replicate this configuration withoud EJB and RestEasy.

How can I inject the SecurityContext in my Controllers?

Comment: If you're using Spring MVC, you'd be much better off just using Spring Security.